Can a race condition occur between a button press callback and a waiting promise in Javascript?
I have a settings page in html, and its corresponding .js file.
The settings page has a list of values obtained from the backend that the user can change. It also has an Apply button at the end.
If the user clicks Apply a $("#settings").submit(... callback is invoked that displays a modal giving the user some information and an OK button. The user can close the modal X or click OK.
On clicking OK the callback (a) $("#OK-btn").on("click"... is invoked that sets a boolean apply_changes to true (defaulted to false).
Back in the $("#settings").submit(... (after displaying the modal) it creates a new Promise((resolve) => ... that in turn does (b) modal.addEventListener("click"... that tests the boolean apply_changes.
My question; can a race condition occur after the user clicks the modal OK, between the callback (a) that sets the boolean, and the Promise callback (b) that tests it?
During testing, I have not seen any race conditions as yet, but would like to know what is happening in the background.
$("#settings").submit()... <displays> --->  Modal OK  ---> $("#OK-btn").on("click"... (a) set apply_changes
                  |                               ^
              <creates>                           |
                  |                               |
                  V                               |
new Promise((resolve) => eventListener("click")----
                         (b) test apply_changes

Edit 12-11-2024
As per comment below by @Bergi, there should be no race conditions; "What matters more than (registration) order is that the event bubbles from one element to the other".
I also reworked my solution (as per @Bergi) so as to simplify it. I no longer use a Boolean (and therefore no inline handler to set it). Instead I used '$(document.activeElement).is()' in my listener to identify where the event originated from to determine my actions.

Please post the actual code, it's hard to tell what's going on from your description.

Since event listeners run asynchronously, there will certainly be a window where other code can run while waiting for the user to click something.

But unless there's other code that sets the variable, I'm not sure how that could be relevant to your situation.

What does "it creates a new Promise […] that tests the boolean apply_changes" mean specifically? Why are you having two event listeners in the first place? Use only one, from which you resolve the promise with a boolean value.

I think the promise is a red herring here. The only race condition exists between the dispatch of the click event, and the first (jQuery) event listener registering another event listener to handle that very click event. So no, there is no race condition, this is deterministic and can be found in the spec; ignoring changes to the jQuery library you're safe here. But still, this is very confusing code that is prone to breaking, and is better solved with only a single event listener where you can clearly see what is happening and when the promise is getting resolved.

I was referring to a race between an inline 'onclick' handler (setting a Boolean) and an eventlistener (reading it). Will inline handlers get invoked before eventlisteners? Is this because they are registered first? The reason I used a Promise was because I wanted my 'submit' listener to wait for a modal to be displayed and clicked, but mine continued processing before I could react to the modal.

No, doesn't matter whether they're inline or installed with jQuery or installed with addEventListener. What matters more than order is that the event bubbles from one element to the other

I'm risking some reputation here... But I'll gamble a little...
For short...

"Can a race condition occur after the user clicks the modal OK, between the callback (a) that sets the boolean, and the Promise callback (b) that tests it?"

Yes! It can. How to do it? Well... that's another question.
But, I want to remind that a race is something asynchronous that happens between promises. It's like "give me the result of the promise (in a set of them) that fulfills first".
Your example/explanation/details only points out one Promise. So where's the need for a race?
I'm guessing you have a submit event handler that shows the modal and sets the promise... Then you want the promise to await for the ok button effect on the modal? If so you can try something like this:


const form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const modal = document.querySelector('#myModal');
const modalButton = modal.querySelector('#myOk');
const variable = document.querySelector('#myVar');

form.addEventListener('submit', submitEventListener);
modalButton.addEventListener('click', okEventListener);

function okEventListener ( event )
{
  variable.value =
  (
    (variable.value == 'true')
    ? 'false'
    : 'true'
  );
  
  modal.open = false;
  
  console.log('OK sets a new variable value:', variable.value);
  
  event.target.resolver(variable.value);
}

async function submitEventListener ( event )
{
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Do ajax stuff here...
  
  let newPromise = new Promise
  (
    async ( resolve, reject ) =>
    {
      modalButton.resolver = value => resolve(value);
    }
  );
  
  modal.open = true;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log('Current variable value:', variable.value);
  
  // You can make any race here, including newPromise and your
  // ajax stuff.
  console.log('Suppose that a race is running starting now.');
  
  // This will await for the user to click ok on the modal,
  // because only by clicking ok the promise fulfills.
  await newPromise; // or change to await your race...
  
  // Then print something to the console...
  console.log("Awaited for the variable changed value:", variable.value);
}
dialog
{
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid black;
}
<dialog id="myModal">
  <button id="myOk">OK</button>
</dialog>
<form method="dialog" action="about:blank" id="myForm">
  <label for="myVar">
    VARIABLE:
    <input type="text" id="myVar" name="myVar" value="true" disabled="disabled" />
  </label>
  <button id="openModal" type="submit">Open Modal</button>
</form>



PS.: As no code was exposed in the question, I made one out of my imagination as an example.

Thanks @KLASANGUI, I am new to javascript and updating existing code hence the lack of an example.
That is basically the flow except the modal is defined in the html and displayed before the Promise is created.
The Promise creates a "click" listener (resolve) for the modal that tests the boolean.
I would think there could be a race between clicking OK (setting the boolean in the okEventListener), and testing the boolean in a new listener of the Promise as they are both async?
